# Bitnami jenkins Failed to start LSB: bitnami init script

Tags: jenkins, google-cloud-platform, bitnami

I'm trying to upgrade my jenkins instance RAM at GCP. It's all normal until I start again the instance. It starts gracefully but cannot run the jenkins service.

```
Jun 24 12:44:57 jenkins-1-vm bitnami[6657]: no listening sockets available, shutting down
Jun 24 12:44:57 jenkins-1-vm bitnami[6657]: AH00015: Unable to open logs
Jun 24 12:44:57 jenkins-1-vm bitnami[6657]: ## 2021-06-24 12:44:57+00:00 ## INFO ## Running /opt/bitnami/var/init/post-start/010_bitnami_agent_extra…
Jun 24 12:44:57 jenkins-1-vm bitnami[6657]: ## 2021-06-24 12:44:57+00:00 ## INFO ## Running /opt/bitnami/var/init/post-start/020_bitnami_agent…
Jun 24 12:44:57 jenkins-1-vm bitnami[6657]: ## 2021-06-24 12:44:57+00:00 ## INFO ## Running /opt/bitnami/var/init/post-start/030_update_welcome_file…
Jun 24 12:44:57 jenkins-1-vm bitnami[6657]: ## 2021-06-24 12:44:57+00:00 ## INFO ## Running /opt/bitnami/var/init/post-start/040_bitnami_credentials_file…
Jun 24 12:44:57 jenkins-1-vm bitnami[6657]: ## 2021-06-24 12:44:57+00:00 ## INFO ## Running /opt/bitnami/var/init/post-start/050_clean_metadata…
Jun 24 12:44:57 jenkins-1-vm systemd[1]: bitnami.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jun 24 12:44:57 jenkins-1-vm systemd[1]: bitnami.service: Failed with result ‘exit-code’.
Jun 24 12:44:57 jenkins-1-vm systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: bitnami init script.
```

I spent hours for walk around try to fix this issue but still cannot find any solution. Any suggestion how can I fix it?

Many thanks.

Comment: If you go back to previous RAM amount and start the instance, does Jenkins work again?

Comment: What kind of instance are you launching? Note that Jenkins requires at least 1536 MB of RAM.

Comment: @Sergiusz it still the same that the services still not working

Comment: @DavidGomez Im launching jenkins from bitnami gcp

Comment: @DavidGomez asked you for the amount of RAM memory the instance has now and had before modifying that value. Jenkins requires 1536 MB of RAM to work properly, does your instance meet that requirement?

Comment: @JotaMartos my instance running on 4 GB before and i upgrade it to 8 GB. based on DavidGomez, my instance meet the requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After walk around and asking to Bitnami support for Jenkins, finally I got the point of the issues. The log doesn't provide me the real issue when i checked it. So, Its just because bitnami automaticly running apache on the instance when I restart again. Just stop and disabled the apache service then try to start the bitnami service. bitnami works well again. you can see [here](https://community.bitnami.com/t/bitnami-jenkins-failed-to-start-lsb-bitnami-init-script/96847), the full step how to fixing the problem with support tools from bitnami.

Comment: the link you mentioned is not the issue link, Please mention the correct link than repo

Comment: I'm sorry, that link supposed to be a direct questions from me to bitnami support back then. really don't know why is it directly to a repo now. I'm trying to look for the for others solution and edit the answer if i found one.

Answer (score 0):

If going back to previous RAM amount does not solve the issue, then the issue lies somewhere else.
I suspect bitnami config files have been corrupted when the VM has been stopped.
Try re-deploying and make sure you shutdown the system gracefully (e.g. `shutdown -h`) before changing specs.

Comment: Hello @Sergiusz, thank you for your suggestion. before I changing my specs, gcp alert me for corrupting data if the shutdown takes time about 90 seconds, so when I take down the instance its just takes time about 15 seconds. I guess my shutdown clearly fine and not affect anything to my data/config. I finally found whats wrong to my instace, i will update an answer for explainig the issue. But, your answer is one of some solving way! thank you!